# Why is there a \\ getting appended in my object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting three arguments in my callback, filePath, stat and name. I need to form a object out of it before passing it to my async function.

```
var config = {};
walk('directory', function(filePath, stat, name) {
    console.log("filePath", filePath);
    config.input = filePath;
    config["output"] = path.join("json", name + ".json");   
});
```

Below is the **output**:

```
FilePath: word\file1.doc
{ input: 'word\\file1.doc', output: 'json\\file1.doc.json' }
FilePath: word\file2.doc
{ input: 'word\\file2.doc', output: 'json\\file2.doc.json' }
```

**Why is there a \ getting appended in my object?** Though my FilePath has only a single slash.

Comment: The values are being shown as they would be written in code, as string literals, with [appropriate escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). The two slashes together represent a single slash in the value.

Comment: How are you getting `{ input: 'word\\file2.doc', output: 'json\\file2.doc.json' }` printed to the console?

Comment: @KevinB: When i print the config object, i get the output. i don't need double slash... all i need is a single slash.

Comment: @Shane There aren't actually two slashes in the value. That's just how a single slash is being represented when printed to the console. A minimal check would be to compare their `.length`s against the number of characters printed out.

Comment: Open the node REPL and compare the output of `console.log('\\bar')` and `console.log({foo: '\\bar'})`. Same string, different output.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Then how come printing FilePath to console prints only one slash and when i add it to object it prints two slashes?

Comment: Because apparently `console.log` treats strings and objects (or rather strings inside objects) differently. You might have notice for example that the object output includes the quotation marks, while the string output does not. Does that mean your string inside the object literally contains quotation marks? Of course not. There is no standard for `console.log`, so implementors can pretty much do whatever they want.

Comment: @Shane `console.log()` via [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) treats the 1st argument, when it's a string, differently. Try `console.log('%j', value);` and the string will get the same format for it as when logging an object with that string.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, i understood.... i was bit confused.... got it.. thanks